# Options \includestandalone + rotate

Tags: standalone

I use \includestandalone for manipulating as an image a TikZ code and I want to be capable to rotate this TikZ code without modifying it, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}   

\begin{document}

... 

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includestandalone[width=.85\textwidth]{model-physics}
%model-physics is a TikZ code
\end{center}
\end{figure}
...

\end{document}
```

Is there any option of `\includestandalone` (e.g. `\includestandalone [rotate=any degrees`, or something like that) that allows me to do this?

If there is, could you expose in an example, please?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is something like that, actually if you take a look at the `standalone`
[package manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) :

> The macro accepts the same options as `\includegraphics` as well as any options suitable for `\standaloneconfig`.

So just add `angle=90,origin=c` as an option.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}   

\begin{document}

... 

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includestandalone[width=.85\textwidth,angle=90,origin=c]{model-physics}
%model-physics is a TikZ code
\end{center}
\end{figure}
...

\end{document}
```